# Is defining an inner function inside a recursive function a bad idea?

Tags: python, recursion

I have some recursive backtracking code that tests if a choice is valid before making it. Is it a bad idea to nest the `is_legal_choice` function inside the recursive `solve` function?  Will this inner function be redefined each time the `solve` function is called?

Comment: The function *object* will be recreated each time your function is called. That's not as bad as it sounds; the code object is already present and the function object creation is relatively light-weight.

Comment: If it makes sense to you from a maintenance / readability perspective, don't worry too much about the function object creation overhead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'll do that...thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the inner function will be redefined each time the function is called. However, it's not as bad as you might assume; the Python code is parsed into a code object once, and only the function object (which serves as a sort of wrapper for the code object) is built anew each time through.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This makes sense and is informative!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be redefined every time it is called. However, it's not always a bad idea. This is how you would make a closure, which is sometimes useful.

If your `is_legal_choice` function needs to use some data that's only available within the scope of the outer function I'd say go for it. The performance overhead won't be too big (you can always profile if you need to).

If `is_legal_choice` doesn't need any data from `solve`'s parameters, do whatever makes your code most understandable.

You can find more information on closures with google, but here's an example: http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html